# what is best practice for multiple inheritance in python classes?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I had a primary class and all of the functionality of my module was implemented in the main class.

```
class Main:
    def __init__():
        ...

    def do_for_all(self):
        return "do something for all"

    def do_a(self):
        return "do something for a"

    def do_b(self):
        return "do something for b"

    def do_c(self):
        return "do something for c"
```

after a while I decided to change my module and architecture:
(* because of the different method diamond problems does not occur)

```
class Main:
    def __init__():
        ...

    def do_for_all(self):
       return "do something for all"


class A(Main):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()

    def do_a(self):
        self.do_for_all()
        return "do something for a in A class"

    def renew_a(self):
        return "new a"


class B(Main):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()

    def do_b(self):
        self.do_for_all()
        return "do something for b in B class"

    def renew_b(self):
        return "new b"


class C(Main):
     def __init__():
         super().__init__()

     def do_c(self):
         self.do_for_all()
         return "do something for c in C class"

    def renew_c(self):
         return "new c"
```

and also as grown-up,scale of my module and features of each of these new classes need a new child:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def do_something(self):
        return "hi"


class MainTypeOne(Parent):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()

    def do_for_all_one(self):
        return "do something for all in first type"


class MainTypeTwo(Parent):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()

    def do_for_all_two(self):
        return "do something for all in second type"


class A(MainTypeOne, MainTypeTwo):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()

    def do_a(self):
       self.do_something()
       return "do something for a in A class"

    def renew_a(self):
       return "new a"


class B(MainTypeOne, MainTypeTwo):
    def __init__():
       super().__init__()

    def do_b(self):
       self.do_something()
       return "do something for b in B class"

    def renew_b(self):
       return "new b"


class C(MainTypeOne, MainTypeTwo):
    def __init__():
       super().__init__()

    def do_c(self):
       self.do_something()
       return "do something for c in C class"

    def renew_c(self):
       return "new c"


class ChildC(C):
    def __init__():
       super().__init__()

    def do_c_child(self):
       return "do something for C's child"


class ChildB(B):
    def __init__():
       super().__init__()

    def do_b_child(self):
        return "do something for B's child"
```

now my main problem is here:
i have defined **init**.py like blow:

```
class Module(ChildB,ChildC):

    def __init__():
       super().__init__()
```

so instead of instantiating from each child class(ChildB,ChildC) I want to just create a new object by calling Module and access to all of the methods of may parent class and others ...

please help me to find out the best solution
and also if you know announce some libraries or frameworks which do this approach.

first of all i want to know if is any problem in this implementation?
then i want to access to all of methods with just one instance but also i want to divide methods by their different type (classification them)
for example i can access to ChildC and ChildB by instantiate them like blow:

```
new_child_c=ChildC()
new_child_b=ChildB()
```

but i want this:

```
new_module=Module() # access to ChildC and ChildB
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with multiple inheritance? Because if some parent classes add just (a bit of) extra functionality, you could consider using mixin classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to wrap my head around the description, but it sounds like something where you should strongly consider using composition (and delegation) rather than inheritance. (Or designing the base classes as mixins, yes.) More importantly, though, I'm worried that you might be trying to treat Python like Java (just, you know, with multiple inheritance). We don't need all our code to be in classes, and `__init__.py` files usually don't contain anything (sometimes they have a custom `__all__` to control the behaviour of `from mypackage import *`).

Comment: "and also if you know announce some libraries or frameworks which do this approach." Sorry, we don't do such recommendations here. If there are some that can be found with a search engine, then that is [your responsibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592); we will not [choose between them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for you, because it is subjective.

Comment: Adding to @9769953: I could see *some* benefit if the interface for all of them provided a `do` method (so no matter which child class you made, you could `do` things with it, and multiple inheritance with `super()` might let you `do` multiple things for a subclass with multiple inherited `do`s), but if they each provide a separately named `do_X` method, they're not remotely interchangeable.

Comment: At the very least, read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on using `super`, especially with `__init__`. (There's really not enough specific information here to tell if there is a legitimate reason for  splitting `Main` into this many classes or not.)

Comment: thank you so much.
you mean it dose not matter to implement every thing in class? , i can do some of them in functional programming instead ?

Comment: @h.j: The proper term for "doing everything with functions" is "procedural programming" (functional programming means something different, though it is something you can do, to an extent, in Python), but yes, if you don't have state to tie to your methods, and there's no benefit being derived from polymorphic inheritance, plain old functions work fine.

Comment: @ShadowRanger can you guide me to know about functional programming and give some useful reference

Comment: @KarlKnechtel very very tanks delegation is the missed concept that I wanted it.